# value of k so that equation have non zero soution

Tags: determinant

\begin{equation}
x+ky-z=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
3x-ky+z=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x-3y+z=0
\end{equation}

the problem that I am having is that it's in the form  homogeneous equation so $x=y=z=0$. Thus, my answer is that it can take value but my books mention the answer as 1.

Comment: Use mathjax please

Answer (score 2):

Your system depends on $k$. If for some value of $k$ the determinant of your system is zero, then you may find more than one solution.

Try $k=3$ and check $ (x,y,z)=(0,1,3)$ as an answer different from $(0,0,0)$

As a result if your determinant is zero, then the solutions are  not necessarily unique.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the first two equations, $4x = 0$, so $x = 0$.

After substituting $x = 0$, the first two equations become:

$$ky-z=0$$
$$-ky+z=0$$

which is the same line.